# Add a line after an occurrence

Tags: bash, shell, sed

The variables are

```
espejo=u456789
usuario=u123456
grupo=unixgr
```

I want to add after the line occurrence of variable `$espejo`, the text in variables `$usuario` and `$grupo`:

```
cp $DIRECTORY/usu.txt  $DIRECTORY/usu.txt.`date '+%F'`
sed "/${espejo}/a\ ${usuario}                ${grupo}" $DIRECTORY/usu.txt.`date '+%F'` > $DIRECTORY/usu.txt
```

I got this error during the execution:

> sed: 0602-404 Function /u456789/a\u123456                 unixgr cannot be parsed.

I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed "s:${espejo}:${espejo}\n${usuario}                ${grupo}:" $DIRECTORIO/usu.txt.`date '+%F'` > $DIRECTORIO/usu.txt
```

If the above just adds `n` instead of newline, try this:

```
sed "s:${espejo}:${espejo}\
${usuario}                ${grupo}:" $DIRECTORIO/usu.txt.`date '+%F'` > $DIRECTORIO/usu.txt
```

This will append the new variable in new line. I guess you are facing the problem since `${espejo}` contains `/` character in it.

Comment: it dont get the /n as a new line, it writes all in the same line, but without \

Comment: Try the sed with `-e` option

Comment: Check the edit. If the first option did not work, try the second option.

Comment: Finally I got it. You have to add another  \     sed "s:${espejo}:${espejo}\\

Comment: Good to know your issue is solved :) Kindly mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
sed "/${espejo}/a\
${usuario} ${grupo}" $DIRECTORIO/usu.txt.`date '+%F'` > $DIRECTORIO/usu.txt
```

Note that after the backslash on first line there is no any other symbols except new line.

Comment: 1) espejo content could not have regex meta character like `\1^$./` freely (it should be a correct Regex) 2) try with a space between `/` and `a\` on firest line 3) same remarq than 1) for  usuario and grupo varaible (but not excatly same rule in a replacment Regex pattern)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed "/$espejo/r /dev/stdin" file  <<<" ${usuario}                ${grupo}"
```